# How to handle "What are [character name] force powers?" type questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Those questions look like :

> I'm trying to write a Powers and Abilities section for [character name] on Wookieepedia, but [random excuse].
>    blah blah blah ... could someone do the work for me?

We already got 2 of them :

- [Allana Solo's force abilities](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20550/allana-solos-force-abilities)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/what-are-onimis-force-powers

I don't see how to close them. It's on topic and their is a restricted set of force powers that could answer, so it's not a list question.

But, both currently have a negative vote total, showing a high community disapproval.

How should we handle them?

Comment: This seems similar to the "what to do with homework" discussion on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Um... you seem to have answered your own question. We downvote them deep. just because something is not against the rules, doesn't make it quality

Comment: Both of those explicitly mention trying to fill out a Wookiepedia page, but without wanting to do any legwork of their own (hence asking here).  I would guess that's the main reason _both_ were downvoted so far:  The button does say "this question does not show any research effort" after all.

Comment: @Izkata Could you write this as an answer?

Comment: I dislike questions regarding "force powers" outside of a video game as discrete abilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, no one has answered in another way yet, so may as well make my comment an answer as DavRob60 suggests.  'Tis popular anyway...

1) Both questions explicitly mention trying to fill out a Wookiepedia page, but without wanting to do any legwork of their own (hence asking here).

2) When you mouse-over the downvote button, it does say "This question does not show any research effort", so dowvoting it into oblivion certainly seems to be the right thing to do.

3) As mentioned in the question, they *do* otherwise seem to be on-topic.

So I'd say, do nothing.  The community will handle them the way that these two questions have been handled.

---

Additionally, as referenced here: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> We already auto-remove negatively voted unanswered old questions
>   automatically after 30 days, network wide, with no human intervention
>   required.

So as long as no one answers those questions, they really would be handled entirely by the community.

Comment: The questions are not really bad questions.  They were just asked poorly.  I think if the OP had simply asked what force powers has character x demonstrated in the EU the question would have a positive total.  I think its a case of too much context here.

Comment: @Chad I agree, it wouldn't have been _as_ negative, but there would've probably still been several downvotes.  If they named even one ability the character has, then it'd probably have been all (or almost all) positive.

Comment: Being that this is a 5/0, should we petition to make this a FAQ?